# How do i combine 2 query results and export to one csv file?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

suppose i have two db servers.

I have the following script

```
Function Query1($Query1) {
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=db1.com;Initial 
Catalog=Report Server;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query1 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$a=$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close() 
$DataSet.Tables[0]} 

Function Query2($Query2) {
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=db2.com;Initial 
Catalog=Report Server;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query2 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$a=$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close() 
$DataSet.Tables[0]}

$Result1 = Query1 "SELECT  [InstanceName]
      ,[ItemPath]
      ,ca.name as ObjectName
      ,(case
         when ca.type = 1 then 'Folder'
         when ca.type = 2 then 'Report'
         when ca.type = 3 then 'Resources'
         when ca.type = 4 then 'Linked Report'
         when ca.type = 5 then 'Data Source'
         when ca.type = 6 then 'Report Model'
         when ca.type = 7 then ' Report Part (SQL 2008 R2, unverified)'
         when ca.type = 8 then 'Shared Dataset (SQL 2008 R2)'
         when ca.type = 13 then 'PowerBI Report'
        End ) as ObjectType

      ,[UserName]
      ,[ExecutionId]
      ,[RequestType]
      ,[Format]
      ,[Parameters]
      ,[ItemAction]
      ,[TimeStart]
      ,[TimeEnd]
      ,[TimeDataRetrieval]
      ,[TimeProcessing]
      ,[TimeRendering]
      ,[Source]
      ,[Status]
      ,[ByteCount]
      ,[RowCount]
      ,[AdditionalInfo]
  FROM [dbo].[$reportServerView] e
  join Catalog ca
  on ca.Path = e.ItemPath where ItemAction = 'ConceptualSchema'or ItemAction 
  = 'QueryData'";
$Result1 | Export-Csv -Path $file_Path\file.csv -NoTypeInformation

$Result2 = Query2 "SELECT  [InstanceName]
      ,[ItemPath]
      ,ca.name as ObjectName
      ,(case
         when ca.type = 1 then 'Folder'
         when ca.type = 2 then 'Report'
         when ca.type = 3 then 'Resources'
         when ca.type = 4 then 'Linked Report'
         when ca.type = 5 then 'Data Source'
         when ca.type = 6 then 'Report Model'
         when ca.type = 7 then ' Report Part (SQL 2008 R2, unverified)'
         when ca.type = 8 then 'Shared Dataset (SQL 2008 R2)'
         when ca.type = 13 then 'PowerBI Report'
        End ) as ObjectType

      ,[UserName]
      ,[ExecutionId]
      ,[RequestType]
      ,[Format]
      ,[Parameters]
      ,[ItemAction]
      ,[TimeStart]
      ,[TimeEnd]
      ,[TimeDataRetrieval]
      ,[TimeProcessing]
      ,[TimeRendering]
      ,[Source]
      ,[Status]
      ,[ByteCount]
      ,[RowCount]
      ,[AdditionalInfo]
  FROM [dbo].[$reportServerView] e
  join Catalog ca
  on ca.Path = e.ItemPath where ItemAction = 'ConceptualSchema'or ItemAction 
  = 'QueryData'";
$Result2 | Export-Csv -Path $file_Path\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The second query overwrites the results of the 1st query results in the csv file. i need both queries to append to same file, however, i dont really want to use append because everytime i run the script i want the file to be overwritten with new data, as this runs every day

Comment: Can you not use UNION on the queries?

Comment: @Enigmativity well...it doesnt matter, as long as i get results from both servers

Comment: @Enigmativity I am technically looking for something as simple as: $Result1+$Result2 | Export-Csv -Path $file_Path\file.csv -NoTypeInformation, but im pretty sure that syntax is wrong, so not sure what to do

Comment: Why not just create two files and merge them together like this `copy file1.csv+file2.csv combined.csv`?

Comment: @ArneSaupe i guess that is another way...i'll try that in meant time. thanks!

Comment: @ArneSaupe now that i think about it...i can just use -Append on the second query...because the first query will always recreate the file and only second query needs to append to existing!

Comment: Good call, that even easier and you won't have 3 files.

Comment: @ArneSaupe indeed!

Comment: The syntax **`$Result1 + $Result2 | Export-Csv -Path $file_Path\file.csv -NoTypeInformation`** is in fact the correct way how to do this (do ***not*** append the csv outputs but append the object lists instead!) . Have you actually tried this???

Comment: @iRon wait really? i rushed to conclude it was a random syntax since i just thought of it from my head lol. dang, i guess i should really try things out before concluding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [Powershell v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-3) or later?
If so you should be able to do your first query as is, and for your second query use "-Append" to add to the file.

However, that will give you a second header row appearing in the middle of the file.
 To avoid that, you probably need to include

`| Select-Object -Skip 1 |`

Answer (score 1):

Now that i think about it...i can just use -Append on the second query...because the first query will always recreate the file and only second query needs to append to existing!

```
$Result1 | Export-Csv -Path $file_Path\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
$Result2 | Export-Csv -Path $file_Path\file.csv -NoTypeInformation -append
```

Comment: Except that you will get a second header row.  You probably need '| Select-Object -Skip 1 |'